# How can I maintain the same column format in R data frame when i export it as csv?

Tags: r, csv

I have a variable in my R data frame that has a 18 chars. When I use `write.csv(out2, file="ddd.csv", row.names=FALSE )`. I get this specific variable's values in a scientific format. I try to export it as txt and it maintained the same exact structure as I wanted but I need it as a csv format. What can i do in order to maintain the exact format of my R data frame when I export it to csv? 
Thank you,
Ron

Comment: Look at `str(out2)`.  What variable type is that column?  It should be a factor, but it sounds like it is numeric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R will write that column as a number if it thinks that it is a number, rather than a categorical variable.  Compare, for example, the columns in this dataset

```
n <- 5
ids <- replicate(
  n, 
  paste0(
    sample(0:9, 18, replace = TRUE), 
    collapse = ""
  )
)

out2 <- data.frame(
  CategoricalId = factor(ids),
  NumericId     = as.numeric(ids)
)
out2
##        CategoricalId    NumericId
## 1 097572748411056439 9.757275e+16
## 2 455782786931417422 4.557828e+17
## 3 046986020739330140 4.698602e+16
## 4 384292451744509872 3.842925e+17
## 5 787170367185951077 7.871704e+17
```

---

The Excel number formatting dialog options, with output:

[image]

Comment: Hi Richie, Thanks for your help... I try to follow your instructions by writing this code as a test case but I still get the number as scientific.Here is the code that I wrote:
x<-c(11234569879876546543,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,0,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6)
x<-as.factor(x)
write.csv(x,file="test.csv")

Comment: Open the resulting CSV file in a text editor.  You can see that R has written all the digits, in double quotes, just as requested.  Have you been viewing the file in Excel?  Excel has some quirky behaviour where it completely disregards CSV conventions and displays strings that look like numbers as numbers even if they are quoted.   Select the column, right click, "Format Cells...", choose Category = "Custom", choose Type = "0".

Comment: Yes I used Excel, Unfortunately your solution didn't worked out for me in Excel but it was a good solution when i used text editor for presenting the data.Thanks,

Comment: I've added a picture of the dialog in Excel.  If my answer has been useful, you can upvote it by clicking the up arrow on the left.